# How to show the code snippet that is commented with Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

Is is possible to show the source code being commented with Doxygen?

I have tried the following:

```
if (u[index] == ']')  /**< Detailed description after the member */
```

and only got the following result:

```
< Detailed description after the member
```

Is there any way to force Doxygen to show the code snippet along with the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can configure doxygen to include a source browser that contains the code, and put links from the generated documentation to the source code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show a code snippet  and not from the source code itself, use @code, @endcode to enclose a code snippet within the class/method documentation.